# Usage of "comparative + Than" as an adverb

Tags: adverbial-phrases, comparative

In a formal writing, can the sentence:

> 1. I became more interested in mathematics than physics.

be rephrased as:

> 2. I became interested in mathematics more than physics.

Do they both have the same meaning? which one is more appropriate?

As far as I know "more than physics" is an adverb in second sentence and "more interested in mathematics that physics" is subject complement in the first one.

Comment: 1) is written but 2) is heard (said) all over the place.

Comment: @Lambie So 2 is not a good choice in formal writing?

Comment: Correct, 1) is better for writing. I became interested in A, more than B. is more of a spoken form.